# How do I split large objects into packets to send over a socket?

Tags: python, sockets, packet

I need to break a large object (say a File Object) into 4kb sized chunks to send over a socket in my client-server application, but I can't fathom how. I'm using python.

Comment: @lightandlight Do you need to send the actual object, or just the data in the file?

Comment: @ceann The data. My end-goal for this is to stream an mp3, so I would need to send each frame. But right now I just need to figure out how to split large messages

Comment: It's basically the same either way except if it is an object you'll need to pickle it or some other form of serialization first in place of a file.

Comment: @woot yeah I'm reading through the link you added and it looks promising

Answer (score 0):

```
        with open(path-to-file, "rb") as fi:
            buf = fi.read(4096)
            while (buf):
               send(buf)
               buf = fi.read(4096)
```

Where send() is a method that will actually send the 4K chunk of data